# Cron task running but not producing output

Tags: linux, bash, cron, filesystems

I have a very simple cron task I want to run hourly, its a bash script that I want to store the output of in a daily log file. The crontab looks like:

```
[srvc_user]$ crontab -l
15 * * * * /path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +"%Y%m%d").log
```

What I'm seeing from the syslog is that the task is running hourly as scheduled but no new log files are being produced:

```
[root]# journalctl -u crond.service -g script
Aug 17 04:15:02 myhost.server.com CROND[3827797]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)
Aug 17 05:15:01 myhost.server.com CROND[3742589]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)
Aug 17 06:15:01 myhost.server.com CROND[3655718]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)
Aug 17 07:15:01 myhost.server.com CROND[3567401]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)
Aug 17 08:15:01 myhost.server.com CROND[3479789]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)
Aug 17 09:15:01 myhost.server.com CROND[3386346]: (srvc_user) CMD (/path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +").log)

[srvc_user]$ ls /path/to/logs
## No new files here!
```

I can run the script on its own as the crontab user with no problems; I can also copy-paste the full crontab line and it runs the script and pipes the output to the logfile as expected:

```
[srvc_user]$ /path/to/script
# Normal output here!

[srvc_user]$ /path/to/script 2&>1 >> /path/to/logs/script_$(date +"%Y%m%d").log
[srvc_user]$ ls /path/to/logs
# New files here!
```

I also verified that the crontab user has access to the log folder:

```
[srvc_user]$ ls /path/to
drwxr-xr-x 2 srvc_user users    4096 Aug 17 01:26 logs
# other files...
```

Not sure what to look at next.

Comment: escape the percent signs, turn `%` to `\%`

Comment: That was it, thank you! I over-edited my original post, I see how I could have gotten that from the journalctl output now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, your redirects are in the wrong order. To send both standard and error output to the log, you need to put `2&>1` *after* the `>>` redirect. See [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).